# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: java

I'm able to deploy my war fine, when I try to run it, I get some runtime errors in console log

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbcracle:thin(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE = ON)(FAILOVER = ON)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = TSS2A056N1-vip.svr.us.co.net)(PORT = 4329))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = TSS2A056N2-vip.svr.us.co.net)(PORT = 4329)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = atmt01d_taf.co.net)(FAILOVER_MODE = (TYPE = select) (METHOD = basic))))'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:317)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)
at com.jpmc.tss.tspayments.rest.controller.CustomizeColumnsController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$76448fa3.getColumnsToDisplay(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apa
```

I think this is a classpath issue - I made sure both classes12.jar and ojdbc-11.2.0.1.0.jar are in tomcat home/lib and java home/jre/lib/ext and that both of these directories are in the classpath.  I also confirmed that ojdbc-11.2.0.1.0.jar  is in my app's Libraries/Maven Dependencies directory.

At this point I feel like the war should have access to this driver jar.  Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Are you trying to run this on a different computer than you developed on?

Comment: > jdbcracle:thin(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE = ON)

The URL name is correct?? or is this a Typo??

Answer (score 4):

Typo in your connect URL?

```
jdbcracle:thin(DESCRIPTION....
```

Should be

```
jdbc:oracle:thin(DESCRIPTION....
```

Comment: also you should not be using classes12 and ojdbc at the same time.  You should use only the one for the JVM you're running.  IN particular, if you're on Java 6, use ojdbc6, java 5, ojdbc5.  Classes1.2 is a relic from the old java 1.2 days.  Also, they should probably be in your tomcat/lib directory not your jvm.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem - basically my data source connection parameters were wrong.  Had nothing to do with oracle jars on my classpath.