# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jndi, tomcat8

I am trying to connect to the Oracle 11i Database using a TNS URL, a username and a password. The data source is being successfully looked up by JNDI, but I am unable to acquire a connection. Instead I see the following stack trace.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204)
org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getOutOfDateSpanishContent(Unknown Source)
com.myproject.cms.tools.controller.OutOfDateSpanishDrcController.downloadDcrReportAsCsv(OutOfDateSpanishDrcController.java:57)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My Maven set up is as follows.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Spring MVC application has been deployed to Tomcat 8. I have oracle jar file in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` location. My JNDI configuration in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` is given below

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="username" password="password" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="Jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host_name>)(PORT=49125))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(service_name=<service_name>)))" maxTotal="10" maxIdle="5"  poolPreparedStatements="true"  validationQuery="select 1" />
```

My web.xml configuration

```
  <resource-ref>
  <description>
    Resource reference to a factory for java.sql.Connection
    instances that may be used for talking to a particular
    database that is configured in the  configuration for the web application.
  </description>
  <res-ref-name>
    jdbc/myDB
  </res-ref-name>
  <res-type>
    javax.sql.DataSource
  </res-type>
  <res-auth>
    Container
  </res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am able to connect successfully using DriverManager API. I have read the following threads, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried all the suggestions from the accepted solutions, but to no avail.

1. [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found jdbc:oracle:thin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061111/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-jdbcoraclethin)
2. [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441289/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver)
3. [Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274722/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null)

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven setup looks wrong. Please try this:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
 <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
 <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

More details can be found here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for